# How to use Office 365 REST API to create a mailbox?

Tags: office365

Is there any code samples (any language) for creating a mailbox in exchange online through Office 365 REST API? thanks a lot.

Note:
Already found APIs for create contact, send emails etc, but not found anything related to create a mailbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office 365 REST APIs for mail, calendar and contacts don't support creation of new mailboxes or managing them.  We at present support only CRUD for the content in the mailbox.  We are looking into adding REST APIs for mailbox creation and management, but don't have a timeline to share.  You will need to use PowerShell to do this.  See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj907304(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more details.

Comment: How about the following link?
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users